# Mimic a website visit and staying

Tags: curl

EDITED

First, sorry about the extra php tag. I thought a solution with php might be involved.

Second, let me apologize that I am not really familiar with any of the network stuff. I happen to know a little bit of bash so when I need to mimic a standing connection only curl comes to my mind. I know it might not be the best, even correct answer.

Then to answer the "10 s" time question. I am not sure how the website tracks the "on page time". I know some websites do it with .js + php but I am not aware of the exact mechanism here.

Thanks for some comments that now I understand that using curl to send a http request might be different from mimicking a persistent browsing behavior. I will look into Selenium but a bash-friendly command line solution would be much appreciated.

Last, with --keepalive-time I get the exact same result as the command without it. Detailed output. Thanks everyone.

```
    # curl --keepalive-time 20 "http://s.weibo.com/weibo/%25E8%2596%259B%25E4%25B9%258B%25E8%25B0%25A6%2B%25E9%2581%2597%25E6%2586%25BE&Refer=STopic_top" -v
*   Trying 180.149.135.239...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to s.weibo.com (180.149.135.239) port 80 (#0)
> GET /weibo/%25E8%2596%259B%25E4%25B9%258B%25E8%25B0%25A6%2B%25E9%2581%2597%25E6%2586%25BE&Refer=STopic_top HTTP/1.1
> Host: s.weibo.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 08 Sep 2017 23:43:55 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Set-Cookie: U_TRS1=0000004f.76de757d.59b32b3b.b76cc844; path=/; expires=Mon, 06-Sep-27 23:43:55 GMT; domain=.sina.com.cn
< Set-Cookie: U_TRS2=0000004f.76f3757d.59b32b3b.a51684a9; path=/; domain=.sina.com.cn
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
< Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Pragma: no-cache
< DPOOL_HEADER: dagda83
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< SINA-LB:aGEuMjA3LmcxLnlmLmxiLnNpbmFub2RlLmNvbQ==
< Set-Cookie: SWB=usrmdinst_12; path=/
< SINA-TS:YTJlODk4Y2UgMCAwIDAgMTEgMzgK
< 
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="DENY " />
<meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
<title>微博搜索 - 薛之谦 遗憾 - 微博</title>

<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/home?nojs=1">
</noscript>
<link href="https://img.t.sinajs.cn/t4/appstyle/searchV45/css_v6/module/common.css?version=201709071330" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />

 <link href="https://img.t.sinajs.cn/t4/appstyle/searchV45/css_v6/pages/weibo.css?version=201709071330" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8" /><link href="https://img.t.sinajs.cn/t4/appstyle/searchV45/css_v6/module/search_directarea.css?version=201709071330" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
<link href="https://img.t.sinajs.cn/t4/appstyle/searchV45/css_v6/module/general.css?version=201709071330" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
<link href="https://img.t.sinajs.cn/t4/appstyle/searchV45/css_v6/module/hot_ranktit.css?version=201709071330" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 var $CONFIG = {};
  $CONFIG['islogin'] = '0';
 $CONFIG['uid'] = '0';
 $CONFIG['entry'] = 'weisousuo';
  $CONFIG['setCover'] = 1; //ie6hack
 $CONFIG['version'] = '201709071330';
 $CONFIG['bigpipe'] = 'true';
 $CONFIG['timeDiff'] = (new Date() - 1504914235000);
 $CONFIG['product'] = 'search';
 $CONFIG['pageid'] = 'weibo';
 $CONFIG['skin'] = '';
 $CONFIG['lang'] = 'zh-cn';
 $CONFIG['jsPath'] = 'https://js.t.sinajs.cn/t4/';
 $CONFIG['cssPath'] = 'https://img.t.sinajs.cn/t4/';
 $CONFIG['imgPath'] = 'https://img.t.sinajs.cn/t4/';
 $CONFIG['servertime'] = 1504914235;
 $CONFIG['ad_url_jump'] = '';
  $CONFIG['bpType'] = 'main';
  $CONFIG['$webim'] = 0;
 $CONFIG['mJsPath'] = ['https://js{n}.t.sinajs.cn/t4/', 1, 2];
 $CONFIG['mCssPath'] = ['https://img{n}.t.sinajs.cn/t4/', 1, 2];
 $CONFIG['s_domain'] = 'http://s.weibo.com';
 $CONFIG['s_search'] = '%25E8%2596%259B%25E4%25B9%258B%25E8%25B0%25A6%2520%25E9%2581%2597%25E6%2586%25BE';
 </script><!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link href="https://img.t.sinajs.cn/t4/appstyle/searchV45/css_v6/pages/ie_bug.css?version=201709071330" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
<![endif]-->
<link href="https://img.t.sinajs.cn/t4/appstyle/searchV45/css_v6/base/usually.css?version=201709071330" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
<link href="https://img.t.sinajs.cn/t4/appstyle/searchV45/css_v6/module/WB_h5video.css?version=201709071330" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<link href="https://img.t.sinajs.cn/t4/appstyle/searchV45/css_v6/module/rela_person.css?version=201709071330" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
<body class="S_weibo ">
<div class="S_wrap ">
 <div id="weibo_top_public"></div>
<link href="https://img.t.sinajs.cn/t4/appstyle/searchV45/css_v6/module/direct_weiguantuan.css?version=201709071330" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
 <!-- new usercard-->
<script src="https://js.t.sinajs.cn/t5/pack/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
WBWidget({
  }).load();
</script>
<script src="https://js.t.sinajs.cn/t5/pack/static/musicplayer/musicplayer_stk_v6.1.5.js"></script>
    <!-- // <script src="http://js.t.sinajs.cn/trunk_musicplayer/js/exports/musicplayer_stk.js"></script> -->
    <script>
    //设置用户uid 用于同步赞状态
    WEIBO_MUSIC_PLAYER.load({page_id:''});
    //监听赞事件
    //监听分享事件
    WEIBO_MUSIC_PLAYER.on('share', function (evt, song) {
    alert(song.copy);
    song //歌曲的所有信息  
    });
    </script>
<div class="S_main">
 <div class="S_main_bg">
  <div class="search_head clearfix" id="pl_common_searchTop"></div>
  <div class="S_plwrap" id="pl_common_unLogin">
   <div class="S_plc" id="plc_main">
   <div class="S_content clearfix">
  <div class="S_content_l">
   <div id="pl_common_sassfilter"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="S_content_r"></div>
   </div>
  </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="search_footer W_textb">
  <div class="global_footer">
 <div class="other_link clearfix">
  <div class="help_link">
   <p>
   <a class="ico_service" href="http://ir.weibo.com/?bottomnav=1&wvr=5" target="_blank">关于微博</a>
   <a href="http://help.weibo.com/?refer=didao&bottomnav=1&wvr=5" target="_blank">微博帮助</a>
   <a href="http://help.weibo.com/newtopic/suggest?bottomnav=1&wvr=5" target="_blank">意见反馈</a>
   <a href="http://open.weibo.com/?bottomnav=1&wvr=5" target="_blank">开放平台</a>
   <a href="http://hr.weibo.com/?bottomnav=1&wvr=5" target="_blank">微博招聘</a>
   <a href="http://news.sina.com.cn/guide/?bottomnav=1&wvr=5" target="_blank">新浪网导航</a>
   <a href="http://service.account.weibo.com/?bottomnav=1&wvr=5" target="_blank">社区管理中心</a>
   <a href="http://service.account.weibo.com/roles/gongyue?bottomnav=1&wvr=5" target="_blank">微博社区公约</a>
   </p>
   <p class="company"><span class="copy S_txt2">Copyright &copy; 2009-2017 WEIBO 北京微梦创科网络技术有限公司</span>
   <span>
   <a href="http://weibo.com/aj/static/jww.html" target="_blank" class="S_txt2">京网文[2011]0398-130号</a><a href="http://www.miibeian.gov.cn" target="_blank" class="S_txt2">京ICP备12002058号</a>
    </span></p>
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- 返回，分享 -->
  <div class="S_gotop" id="base_scrollToTop">
  <a suda-data="key=tblog_search_weibo&value=weibo_up" node-type="scrollToTop" class="W_gotop S_ficon_bg" href="javascript:void(0);" style="display:;"><em class="W_ficon ficon_backtop S_bg2_c">Ú</em></a> </div>
  <!-- <div class="right_btn" id="base_scrollToTop">
 <ul class="btn_list">
  <li node-type="scrollToTop" style="display:;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="bottom_btn" title=返回顶部 suda-data="key=tblog_search_v4.1&value=weibo_feed_back"><span><em class="btn_icon"><i class="search_icon icon_top"></i></em><em class="btn_txt">顶部</em></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://weibo.com/wbsearch?Refer=STopic_feedback" title=提交使用反馈 target="_blank" class="bottom_btn" suda-data="key=tblog_search_v4.1&value=weibo_feed_feedback"><span><em class="btn_icon"><i class="search_icon icon_feedback"></i></em><em class="btn_txt">反馈</em></span></a></li>
   </ul>
  </div> -->
  <!-- /返回，分享 --> 
  <div style="display:none;" id="pl_common_base"></div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="http://js.t.sinajs.cn/t6/home/js/pl/top/topInit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() { 
 WBtopGlobal && WBtopGlobal.init({
  'islogin': 0,
  "backurl":"http://s.weibo.com"
});
})();
</script>
 <script src="https://js.t.sinajs.cn/t4/apps/search_v6/js/base.js?version=201709071330" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<!-- 视频播放 -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.t.sinajs.cn/video/sinaplayer/js/page/player.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.t.sinajs.cn/t6/page/js/pl/third/search/index.js?version=2017090907"></script>
<!-- SUDA_CODE_START -->
<noscript><img width="0" height="0" src="http://beacon.sina.com.cn/a.gif?noScript" border="0" alt="" /></noscript>
<!-- SUDA_CODE_END -->

<script>STK && STK.pageletM && STK.pageletM.view({"pid":"pl_common_sassfilter","js":["apps\/search_v6\/js\/pl\/common\/sassfilter.js?version=201709071330"],"css":[],"html":"<div class=\"WB_cardwrap S_bg2\">\n<div class=\"code_box clearfix\">\n <div class=\"code_ver\">\n  <p class=\"code_tit\">\u4f60\u7684\u884c\u4e3a\u6709\u4e9b\u5f02\u5e38\uff0c\u8bf7\u8f93\u5165\u9a8c\u8bc1\u7801\uff1a<\/p>\n  <div class=\"code_wrap\">\n <div class=\"form_table veri_code clearfix\">\n  <span class=\"code_input\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"W_inputStp\" node-type=\"yzm_input\"><\/span> \n  <span class=\"code_img\"><img src=\"\/ajax\/pincode\/pin?type=sass&ts=1504914235\" node-type=\"yzm_img\"><\/span>\n  <a class=\"code_change\" node-type=\"yzm_change\" href=\"javascript:void(0);\">\u770b\u4e0d\u6e05\uff0c\u6362\u4e00\u5f20<\/a> \n <\/div>\n <div class=\"veri_state\"><div class=\"M_notice_del\" style=\"display:none;\" node-type=\"yzm_error\"><span class=\"icon_del\"><\/span><span class=\"txt\">\u9a8c\u8bc1\u7801\u9519\u8bef\uff0c\u8bf7\u91cd\u65b0\u8f93\u5165<\/span><\/div><\/div>\n <div class=\"code_btn\"><a class=\"S_btn_b\" href=\"javascript:void(0);\" node-type=\"yzm_submit\"><span>\u6211\u771f\u6ef4\u4e0d\u662f\u673a\u5668\u4eba<\/span><\/a><\/div>\n  <\/div>\n <\/div>\n<\/div>\n<\/div>"})</script>
<script>STK && STK.pageletM && STK.pageletM.view({"pid":"pl_common_base","js":["apps\/search_v6\/js\/pl\/common\/changeLanguage.js?version=201709071330","apps\/search_v6\/js\/pl\/common\/base.js?version=201709071330"],"css":[],"html":""})</script>
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
</html>
```

Original post:

**I want to mimic a web site visit and mimic user staying on the page for more than 10 seconds.**

Right now I have curl do the visit job,but the connection seems to be closed immediately after the curl command finishes. The time spent is negligible.

I have read some threads about --keepalive but it does not seem help.

Result:

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>
> 100  8931    0  8931    0     0  18287      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 18301

Code

```
for i in `seq 1 $count`; do 
    curl "${targeturl}" > /dev/null; 
    sleep 20; 
done
```

I really appreciate any tips on how to do it.

Comment: Show us your attempt with the keepalive option enabled and show exactly what happened with that attempt.

Comment: Staying on a web site in the browser doesn't necessarily keep the connection open the whole time.

Comment: The `--keepalive` option is only relevant if you have multiple URLs on the same server, that makes it use the same connection for all of them. It's not possible to keep the connection open after it finishes processing all the URLs.

Comment: Why are you using curl? Just automate a browser using e.g. Selenium.

Comment: Why is this tagged `php`? You're using `curl` from `bash`.

Comment: What determines you have been on the website for 10 seconds? Does the website have JavaScript tracking the user? HTTP requests by their design are stateless and are designed to be as quick as possible to deliver the requested data.